# Javascript - append to text area value - IE Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript

How do I get this done. I am trying to append text to a text area. If some value already exists then append. I had it working but seems like it cannot work in all browsers. Is there a better way to do this?

Tried both ways, they don't work in Chrome, IE and FF -

```
if ($('#log').value == undefined) {
$('#log').val("First: " + result[0]);
} else {
$('#log').val($('#log').value += "Second: " + result[0]);
}

if ($('#log').value == undefined) {
$('#log').val("First: " + result[0]);
} else {
$('#log').val(log.value += "Second: " + result[0]);
}
```

Without `If`, this works in Chrome but not in IE and FF -

```
$('#log').val(log.value += "First: + result[0]);
```

Comment: undefined is not the same as the empty string, which is the value of an empty text area.

Comment: I don't see why you have an element with `+=` inside its own `.val()`. Try `$('#log').val($('#log').val() + "Second: " + result[0]);`

Comment: @kennebec - In chrome for empty log `$('#log').val(log.value += "First: + result[0]);` get printed as `undefined`. How do detect empty string / text area?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Tried `$('#log').val($('#log').val() + "Second: " + result[0]);`. Same result.

Comment: I see. Any errors in your console?

Comment: `$('#log').value` will always be `undefined` because that's wrong.  jQuery objects don't have a `value` property.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Can't really tell any errors. I am just testing directly in the browser if it works.

Comment: Most browsers come with a Javascript console which may tell you where your code is breaking and why. I'm not very good teaching these basics but well, if you're on Firefox press Ctrl+Shift+K, if you're on Chrome press F12 and click in the Console tab. After that, run your code in the browser and it'll tell you where/why it's breaking. :)

Comment: @Rocket and  Fabrício Matté - Thanks! Understood. Now it worked. :)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: His code doesn't throw any errors, as there are no "errors".  He's just trying to access properties that don't exist, which are just `undefined`.

Comment: Oh damn, I noticed the `.value` inside the .val() but I didn't notice it in the `if` statement. +1 to your answer. :) time to call it a night.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - hahah. Even I missed it. Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery objects don't have a `.value` property, so `$('#log').value` will always be `undefined`.  This means that your statement will always call `$('#log').val("First: " + result[0]);` and never call the second one.

You need to check `if($('#log').val() == '')` instead.

As for [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), you can pass a function.  This function will be passed the current value of the input.

```
if ($('#log').val() == '') {
    $('#log').val("First: " + result[0]);
} else {
    $('#log').val(function(i, v){ // v is the current value
        return v + "Second: " + result[0];  // what's returned is what the value will be set to
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How does it determive that `v` has the text value? and what is `i`?

Comment: When you pass a function to `.val()` jQuery calls it, and passes it 2 parameters.  The first (which I named `i`), is the `index` (position within its parent) of the element, and the second (which I named `v`) is the current value.  The return value of this function is what the element's value will be set to. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Thanks. So jQuery is designed for passing these two parameters.

Comment: Yes, the parameters are passed by jQuery, you're just giving it a function that can accept them.

Comment: Cool. thanks! Didn't know that. I was just dumb code twister so far. :D

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)  JQuery does a lot of neat stuff like that ;-)